# continer cannot contain non null values for an array of panels

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jpanel, grouplayout

I am creating a Java app project that something similar to the one I post below

1. Has a single frame with a label.
2. A `Mastercardpanel` just below the label.
3. An array of panels to be embedded onto the `Mastercardpanel`

Code snippet

```
CardLayout card=new CardLayout(500,500);
 JPanel mastercardpanel=new JPanel();
    JPanel[] cardpanel;
    cardpanel = new JPanel[50];
     mastercardpanel.setLayout(card);
```

Also for each of the card panel's I would use group layout to add some Swing elements.

Code snippet

```
for(t=0;t<50;t++)
    {


    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(cardpanel[t]);
    cardpanel[t].setLayout(layout);
     .
     .
     .
```

My problem is that `GroupLayout` would only accept `cardpanel` as a non-null value. Please suggest how to go about it.

Comment: As near as I can tell, you've not actually added anything to the array, yes you've initialised, but you've not filled it...

Comment: I am new to java programming, so excuse me for my noobness but could you tell how to add content to array of panels. how do you fill it even before grouplayout which was supposed to do the filling with swing elements please give an example thanks

Comment: Try adding `cardpane[t] = new JPanel();` before you create the layout

Answer (score 3):

Try to initialize every cardpanel in array:

```
for(t=0;t<50;t++)
{

cardpanel[t]=new JPanel(null);
javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(cardpanel[t]);
cardpanel[t].setLayout(layout);
 .
 .
 .
```

Comment: Well. If you think that it's correct, please check it, and if it's not resolved let we know and we will help you. Thanks